# При переносе комментариев в чат портится аватарка

Tags: дефект

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560937/178988
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44724/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ruslik

[image: Скриншот]

UPDATE: Похоже, аватарка вообще во всех чатах изменилась, но чужие отображаются верно.

Comment: [из большой меты](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change)

Comment: С новым граватаром вас прямо не узнать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, за что такой статус? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Как я понял, это ошибка граватара.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а не стало известно, чинить будут или нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy К сожалению, пока мне ничего не известно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Еще раз уточнил у ребят. Поскольку ошибка именно на стороне граватара, особо починить ничего не получится, так как граватар – сторонний сервис.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, понятно, что чинить не SO, а граватару. Но логично же, что от них должен быть какой-то фидбек по поводу изменений.

Answer (score 5):

Как было установлено при обсуждении в чате, ***предположительно*** изменился алгоритм генерации идентиконов (автоматических аватарок).

Теперь аватарки на всех сайтах медленно заменяются на новые по мере протухания кэша на сервере. Причем для аватарок разного размера кэш протухает в разное время, отсюда и эффект несоответствия.

На "большой" Мете [рекомендуют](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333531/4340086) вытащить через archive.org свой старый профиль пользователя, из него вытащить картинку, сохранить ее локально - и поставить в качестве аватарки.

Comment: что характерно на archive.org профиля может и не быть, а так же может быть сохранена уже новая картинка

Comment: @Grundy "сохранена новая картинка" следует читать как "нет картинки за нужную дату"

Comment: Надеюсь, они собираются вернуть как было?

Comment: Да, возможно, хотя и странно, когда из трех точек в двух крайних новая а в середине старая

Comment: @Qwertiy, вряд ли.